# S3 image url not working with crystal report 2008

Tags: iis, amazon-s3, crystal-reports

I have an image in "s3". I need to display that image in one crystal report. I have set the graphic location as the s3 image path.When I am debugging, the image is being displayed in crystal report.But when I do the deployment of website through IIS image is not displaying.can any one please help me to fix this.do I need to do any settings in config file specific for this.

I am using VS 2008 and crystal report 2008

Comment: Have you checked the broken image path? Launch browser Developer tools and then switch to Network tab and check the if image path is correct

Comment: under network i cant able to see any request for that s3 url